# Confused as to why Volume Control is not working in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a video player for my Online Scripting class and I have my videos playing, my Play, and my Mute button all working with the correct hover states and everything. They are positioned correctly and ready to go. Now I have to create my Time Slider and my Volume Slider and that is where the difficulty is coming in. I have created an ActionScript 3 file called VolumeBar and I have no idea why it isn't working. In my head, it should work but I think I am missing something.

My Symbols are BTN_Slider, BTN_VolumeBar, and BTN_VolumeBarSlider. None of the tutorials help as they all use the "actions" functions within the frames which I am not doing

Main

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    static public var splash:SplashScreen;
    private var theXMLFile:String = "VideoList.xml";
    private var theVideoList:VideoList;
    private var videoChoice:int = 0;
    private var sndTransform:SoundTransform;
    private var lastVolume:int = 1;
    private var btn_Mute:BTN_Mute;
    private var btn_Play:BTN_Play;
    private var btn_Volume:VolumeBar;
    static public var screenState:int = 0;
    static public var nextState:int = 1;

    public function Main()
    {
        theVideoList = new VideoList(theXMLFile);
        btn_Mute = new BTN_Mute(581.3, 457.5);
        btn_Play = new BTN_Play(42, 457.5);
        btn_Volume = new VolumeBar(624.3, 457.5);
        btn_Mute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedMute);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    private function update(e:Event):void
    {
        switch(screenState)
        {
            case 0 :
                break;
            case 1 :
                videoChoice = 0;
                nextState = 2;
                displayScreen();
                trace("TEST");
                addChild(btn_Volume);
                addChild(btn_Mute);
                addChild(btn_Play);
                break;
            case 2 :
                videoChoice = 1;
                nextState = 3;
                changeScreen();
                break;
        }
        screenState = 0;
    }

    public function displayScreen():void
    {
        splash = new SplashScreen(theVideoList.videoXML.theVideo[videoChoice].fileLoc.text());
        addChild(splash);
    }

    public function changeScreen():void
    {
        var toShow:String = theVideoList.videoXML.theVideo[videoChoice].fileLoc.text();
        splash.connectVideo(toShow);
    }

    private function muteVolume(vol:Number):void
    {
        sndTransform = new SoundTransform(vol);
        splash.vidStream.soundTransform = sndTransform;
    }

    private function clickedMute(mb:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(btn_Mute.isMuted == true)
        {
            muteVolume(lastVolume = 1);
            btn_Mute.isMuted = false;
        }
        else if(btn_Mute.isMuted == false)
        {
            muteVolume(lastVolume = 0);
            btn_Mute.isMuted = true;
        }
    }

    static public function togglePlay():void
    {
        splash.vidStream.togglePause();
    }
}
```

VolumeBar

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class VolumeBar extends MovieClip
{
    var sliderControl = new BTN_Slider();
    var sliderVolume = new BTN_VolumeBar();
    var knobWidth:int = sliderControl.width;
    var trackWidth:int = sliderVolume.width;
    var trackX:int = sliderVolume.x;
    var boundWidth = trackWidth - knobWidth;
    var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(trackX, 0, boundWidth, 0);

    public function VolumeBar(theX:int, theY:int)
    {
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;

        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDragging);
    }

    private function startDragging(mb:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sliderControl.startDrag(false, boundsRect);
    }

    private function stopDragging(mb:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sliderControl.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

All I would like to know right now is HOW to get it on the screen and moveable basically. Once I get that going, I know I can get the rest on my own. Thanks Stack Overflowers!

Comment: does the slider move upon drag ? i think these calculation are wrong :  var trackX:int = sliderVolume.x;
    var boundWidth = trackWidth - knobWidth;
    var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(trackX, 0, boundWidth, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you forget to add the `sliderVolume` and `sliderControl` to the display list ?
 
I think you could do something like this:

VolumeBar.as :

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

public class VolumeBar extends MovieClip
{
    var sliderControl = new BTN_Slider();
    var sliderVolume = new BTN_VolumeBar();
    var knobWidth:int = sliderControl.width;
    var trackWidth:int = sliderVolume.width;
    var trackX:int = sliderVolume.x;
    var boundWidth = trackWidth - knobWidth;
    var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(trackX, 0, boundWidth, 0);

    /** a function to call when volume change **/ 
    private var _volumeChanged:Function;

    public function VolumeBar(theX:int, theY:int, volumeChanged:Function)
    {
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;

                    // add the volume bar to the display list
        addChild( sliderVolume );
                    // add the slider to the display list
        addChild( sliderControl );
        // keep reference to the update function 
        _volumeChanged = volumeChanged;

        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        sliderControl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDragging);
    }

    private function startDragging(mb:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sliderControl.startDrag(false, boundsRect);
        stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _onMouseMove );
    }

    private function stopDragging(mb:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sliderControl.stopDrag();
        stage.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE );
    }

    private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // calculate the volume for the current cursor position
        var value:Number = (trackWidth - sliderControl.x) / boundWidth;
        _volumeChanged( value );
    }
}
```

and change your Main class as follow:

```
public function Main()
{
    theVideoList = new VideoList(theXMLFile);
    btn_Mute = new BTN_Mute(581.3, 457.5);
    btn_Play = new BTN_Play(42, 457.5);

    // add the callback function to the VolumeBar constructor
    btn_Volume = new VolumeBar(624.3, 457.5, _onVolumeChanged);
    btn_Mute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedMute);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

/** handle volume changing **/
private function _onVolumeChanged( value:Number ):void
{
    // change your volume here
}
```

Of course you can use events to do that but i prefer callbacks, and if you prefer you can make the volume change on stop dragging instead of mouseMove.

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! It works and everything! I have a few positioning problems with my slider, but this totally works! Starting to understand ActionScript 3 more and more each day!